# apply path of web font in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, webserver, wordpress-theming

How do I find direct(absolute) path of my files in wordpress theme? For 
example: I created fonts folder in my theme and I don't know direct path of my font files, like: "test.com/dir/dir/fonts/font.woff." How do I find the absolute path?

My theme options have a place to add links of web fonts and I don't know how find path of my font or where is past the fonts for easy access

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your theme comes with fonts? If so, you would be able to see them inside of your theme folder, which will be something like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/
```

You can investigate this using either a File Manager (many of the popular hosts have these in their cPanel...like BlueHost, HostGator, Media Temple, etc) or by logging into FTP and rooting around.

Alternatively, it's possible that it's asking for the link to something like a [Google Font](https://www.google.com/fonts/). For example, the following would be a link to Open Sans, a very popular web font.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans
```

Comment: thanks for reply, problem is solved, I use upload folder for this. google font is for english and my blog isn't.